# how to make heads-up notifications in android studio?

Tags: android

As I've searched how to reveal heads-up, I found a solution that is to set priority high but it still doesn't show heads-ups. I've got a notfication massenger service. Its function is as below. Is there anything I missed in settings?

### Heading

mycode:

```
private void sendNotification(String body, String title) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Firebase");
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.body, body);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, new Intent[]{intent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(remoteViews)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setTicker(body)
            .setSound(notificationSound)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notifBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)` with `.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)` in your Notification Builder.